# pagination link not showing the values in codeigniter,

Tags: php, codeigniter

Whenever i click on the links of pagination...it shows obeject not found.I am not getting how to pass the value to {index.php/view_expenses/view&per_page=2 } this page.Dont mind if this is a stupid question im just 2month older in php and codeigniter.Any help will be great :D
**This is my controller**

```
    function view($offset=0)
    {
        $limit=5;
        $this->uri->segment(3);
        $this->load->model('emp_expenses_model');
        $result['contents']=$this->emp_expenses_model->getRows($limit,$offset);
        $result['countRows']=$this->emp_expenses_model->countRows();
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $this->load->library('table');

        $config=array(
                    'base_url' => '/index.php/view_expenses/view',
                    'total_rows' => $this->db->get('emp_expenses')->num_rows($limit,$offset),
                    'per_page' => $limit,
                    'uri_segment' => 3,
                    'num_links' => 1,
        );   

        $this->db->limit(5);
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $this->load->model('emp_expenses_model');
        $this->data['view_expenses'] = $this->emp_expenses_model->get_all();
        //var_dump($this->data['pay_list']);die("jk");
        $this->data['title'] = 'Payroll System';
        $this->data['message'] = $this->session->flashdata('message');
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $this->load->view('view_expenses', $this->data);
        /*$this->load->view('add_list', $this->data);*/
}
```

**This is my model**

```
function getRows($limit,$offset)
{
    $query=$this->db->select('expenses_id,id,dropdown,modeofpayment,amount')
       ->from('emp_expenses')
       ->limit($limit,$offset);

    $result=$query->get()->result_array();
    return $result;
}

function countRows()
{
    $query="select count(*) as count from emp_expenses";
    $result=$this->db->query($query);
    return $result->result_array();
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't really be using database queries in your controller. Instead of `'total_rows' => $this->db->get('emp_expenses')->num_rows($limit,$offset)` , should it not be `'total_rows' => $result['countRows']`

Answer (score 0):

To create the pagination HTML, you can to call `create_links()`, and then pass this to your view with the other data. This will automatically generate the correct links for you. Try including this in your controller:

`$this->data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();`

Make sure you call it after `$this->pagination->initialize($config);`

Then in your view:

`echo $pagination;`

Comment: Thats not working its creating links but when i click on those links its shows 404 error.

Comment: you may also need to use `$config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;` in your config, as your using the query string not segments for your urls.

Comment: i have done that also.$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
$config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;

Answer (score 0):

Changes in your **model**:

```
function countRows(){
    //$query="select count(*) as count from emp_expenses";
    $result = $this->db->count_all_results('emp_expenses');
    //$result=$this->db->query($query);
    return $result;
}
```

In your controller change the follwing lines,

```
$result['countRows']=$this->emp_expenses_model->countRows();
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $this->load->library('table');
    $config=array(
                    'base_url' => '/index.php/view_expenses/view/',
                    'total_rows' => $result['countRows'],
                    'per_page' => $limit,
                    'uri_segment' => 3,
                    'num_links' => 1,
     );
```

You are loading the `model` two times I see, comment the second one. Why are you using `$result['contents']=$this->emp_expenses_model->getRows($limit,$offset);` if you are not loading it in view?

In your view call `<?=$this->pagination->create_links()?>` to see the pagination.

Comment: thnks niloy for finding those errors.but still its not solving my problem...pagination is not working :( why in this page result is not showing view_expenses/view&per_page=2 ?

Comment: See the comment to my answer, it may help. You need to set a config variable for `$config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;` because you are using the query string to get your per_page variable.